# extracting rendering information of DOM elements

Tags: html, dom, information-extraction

Is there any way of extracting the rendering information of the DOM elements such as the position, the font, the color, etc? For example, a HTML file may not specify the coordinates of  tags but the web browser engine will somehow calculate their positions and the relative size. I am wondering how I can make a program access the information

I know that I can manually access the rendering information, for example, using "Inspect element" in Google chrome but am wondering if there is any programmable way.

Thanks

ps. I guess I have to provide the context of this task. I am currently working on Information Extraction on the structured data (e.g., tables) in a HTML webpage and am thinking of using visual information (e.g., the locations of the table elements) to extract the structured information.

Comment: This basically requires simulation of much of what browsers do in rendering, and it would really depend on the programming language and tools you would be using. A really broad question.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can use `someElement.getBoundingClientRect()`, which returns an object containing `left`, `top`, `width` and `height` properties.

You can also use `window.getComputedStyle(someElement)` (older IE uses `someElement.currentStyle`) to get various computed CSS information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But, my purpose is to analyze the web pages written by others rather than using the visual information in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, all of this information is available using javascript. Are you familiar with the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library? There is a jQuery method called .css() that you should familiarize yourself with. Using a jQuery selector, you can query any DOM element that you can select. So to find out the color of an h1 element on your page, you can say

```
$('h1').css('color');
```

And get back

```
"rgb(0, 0, 0)"
```

Here is a decent rundown of jQuery selectors (not a big fan of w3 schools, but this suffices for a beginning glance: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp